# Annotations data is not present for @Service marked class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, annotations

I'm trying to implement resolver pattern ( strategy pattern ).

So I have one custom annotation `@PaymentTypeValue`

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface PaymentTypeValue {
    PaymentType[] value();
}
```

and `PaymentType` as enum class

```
public enum PaymentType{
CASH, CARD, NET_BANKING, UPI, WALLET;
}
```

now I have interface `PaymentService`

```
public interface PaymentService {
   void process();
}
```

and have its 5 implementations, one is like

```
@Service
@PaymentTypeValue({PaymentTypeValue.CASH})
public class CashPaymentService implements PaymentService {
  @Override
  void process(){
    //some logic
  }
}
```

And I have resolver which is like this

```
@Component
public class PaymentServiceResolver {

    private static final Logger log = getLogger(PaymentServiceResolver.class);

    @Autowired
    private List<PaymentService> paymentServices;

    private final Map<PaymentType, PaymentService> paymentServiceMap = new EnumMap<>(PaymentType.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        paymentServices.forEach(paymentService -> {
                    PaymentTypeValue annotation = paymentService.getClass().getAnnotation(PaymentTypeValue.class);
                    if (annotation != null && annotation.value() != null) {
                        PaymentType[] paymentTypes = annotation.value();
                        Arrays.stream(paymentTypes).forEach(paymentType -> {
                            paymentServiceMap.put(paymentType, paymentService);
                        });
                    } else {
                        log.error("paymentService {} is missing a necessary annotation",
                                paymentService.getClass().getName());
                        log.error("This paymentService cannot be initialized");
//                        throw new IllegalStateException("paymentService is missing a necessary annotation for " + paymentService.getClass().getName());
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public PaymentService resolvePaymentService(PaymentType paymentType) {
        PaymentService paymentService = paymentServiceMap.get(paymentType);
        if (paymentService != null) {
            return paymentService;
        } else {
            String message = "Could not find paymentService for " + paymentType;
            log.error(message);
            throw new RuntimeException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is in init() method, all the service implementations of `PaymentService` are present in list but when i'm trying to find annotations its giving null.
I checked the value of `paymentService.getClass()` method and in that annotationData had 0 annotations. If I autowire any specific implementation of PaymentService then I'm able to get the annotation value. Please help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: You probably get a proxy instead of the actual object. I suggest to use the `AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(Class, Class)` method from Spring to find the annotation (it traverses the hierarchy and thus works with proxies). Also the `@Component` on the annotation isn't really needed, doesn't add anything really.

Comment: hey @M.Deinum Thanks for the response. I tried that and it worked. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation approach makes things complex, I would try to avoid that. A simpler solution without annotations, assuming that there is a 1:1 mapping between `PaymentType` and service implementation:

1. Add a function `boolean canHandle(PaymentType)` to the service interface.
2. A resolver uses that information to locate a matching service.

Interface:

```
public interface PaymentService {

    boolean canHandle(PaymentType paymentType);

    void process();
}
```

Service implementation:

```
@Service
public class CashPaymentService implements PaymentService {

    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(PaymentType paymentType) {
        return PaymentType.CASH.equals(paymentType);
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        // processing...
    }
}
```

Service locator:

```
@Component
public class PaymentServiceResolver {

    private final List<PaymentService> paymentServices;
    private final Map<PaymentType,PaymentService> serviceMapping = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(5);

    @Autowired
    public PaymentServiceResolver(List<PaymentService> paymentServices) {
        this.paymentServices = paymentServices;
    }

    public PaymentService resolve(PaymentType paymentType) {
        return serviceMapping.computeIfAbsent(paymentType, resolveInternal());
    }

    private Function<PaymentType, PaymentService> resolveInternal() {
        return paymentType ->
                paymentServices.stream()
                        .filter(service -> service.canHandle(paymentType))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Unsupported payment type: " + paymentType));
    }
}
```

You may add more validation logic to your resolver to check during the Spring's initialization phase whether an implementation is available for each `PaymentType`.

Comment: Hey! Really appreciate your response. Personally I will not prefer to go with method `canHandle()` as every impl class has to maintain it and if something goes wrong will need to check the implementation of each class. right now for 2 payment types i have only one implementation  so I have to add `or ` condition to make it work. Also the annotation based approach tells me that each PaymentService implementation must be tied with at least one PaymentType.